# Kivy screen becomes unresponsive

Tags: python, audio, kivy

I'm making an app in Kivy after switching from Pygame (Kivy is much more appropriate for an app like this one) and I seem to be encountering the same problem as I did before. Once a function gets called via pressing of a button, It has to run its course. Clicking anywhere on the screen before that will result in the screen going unresponsive. I'd like for the user to be able to stop halfway through. I have assigned a "stop_function" function (it changes condition "function_stop" from the main function technically stopping it from executing) to a "Stop" button in .kv file too but I am unable to click it.

There is another problem too. The function is meant to play a sound at random time intervals but it only plays the sound once. The loop still loops as I am checking it via print statements but the sound is not playing.

I hope someone can help. Here is a snippet of my code:

> class MyApp(App):
> def build(self):
> return kv
>
> ```
> def play_tech(self, new_dict):
>     technique = (random.choice(session_list))
>     print(technique)
>     new_dict[technique].play()
>
> def in_session(self):
>     function_stop = False
>     now = time.time()
>     global timer
>     timer = 0
>     while timer < int(session_time) and function_stop == False:
>         play_tech(cog_dict)
>         end = time.time()
>         timer = round(end - now)
>         print(timer)
>         time.sleep((cooldown + random.randint(0, 4)))
>     return
>
> def stop_function(self):
>     function_stop = True
>     print
> ```

And the respective part of the .kv file:

> ```
> FloatLayout:
>
>     Button:
>         text: "Back"
>         font_size: 0.4 * self.height
>         size_hint: 0.1, 0.08
>         pos_hint: {"x": 0.45, "y": 0.05}
>         on_release:
>             app.root.current = "cog"
>             root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
>
>     Button:
>         text: "Start"
>         size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
>         pos_hint: { "x": 0.2, "y": 0.1}
>         on_release:
>             app.in_session()
>
>     Button:
>         text: "Stop"
>         size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
>         pos_hint: { "x": 0.6, "y": 0.1}
>         on_release:
>             app.stop_function()
> ```

I hope someone can shed some light onto this. If you require full code, just let me know.

Many thanks to whoever is looking at this.

Comment: Your `in_seession()` method is running on the main thread and not allowing kivy to respond to events (like button presses).  Just modify your code to run `in_session()` on another thread.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. That makes sense although I can't seem to get it to work. Do I leave the method where it is and just create a method which will create a new thread when the in_session()  is executed? Like :                                                      th = Thread(target=in_session, args=())                                                                                         th.daemon = True                                                                                                                     th.start()

Comment: Thank you again. I've managed to create another thread for the function and it all runs fine and I am able to press all the buttons while it's executing. Feel free to post this comment as an answer. I have however one more question. The sounds played during the functions execution are being cut short. Any idea what may cause this? I cannot find any indication of a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the while loop, as well as the sleep() function within.

In Kivy, everything, events,functions etc run within a main loop that repeatedly runs throughout the lifetime of your app, receiving input and doing many other stuff within each iteration.

When you call the in_session() method, the loop remains on that iteration until the while loop is done. This is a problem because Kivy cannot receive input or rather do anything whilst still in that one iteration, thus the app becoming unresponsive.

To solve this use Clock.schedule_interval(), or Clock.schedule_once() or Clock.create_trigger() functions.
For example, in my case I used Clock.schedule_interval() ;

1. Use the Clock.schedule_interval() method to repeatedly call a function (in my case, a RootLayout() method, on_session_begin() ) that shall call the play_tech() method and other processes that you want.

```py
self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.root_layout.on_session_begin, 1./60.)
```

2. Then in the stop_function() method, stop the on_session_begin() calls by using;

```py
self.event.cancel()
```

Here is the code I used;

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random

kv = '''
<RootFloatLayout>:

    Label:
        text: root.label_string

    Button:
        text: "Back"
        font_size: 0.4 * self.height
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.08
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.45, "y": 0.05}
        # on_release:
        #     app.root.current = "cog"
        #     root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

    Button:
        text: "Start"
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
        pos_hint: { "x": 0.2, "y": 0.1}
        on_release:
            app.in_session()

    Button:
        text: "Stop"
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
        pos_hint: { "x": 0.6, "y": 0.1}
        on_release:
            app.stop_function()
    
'''

Builder.load_string(kv)

class RootFloatLayout(FloatLayout):

    label_string = StringProperty('Hello World!')

    def play_tech(self):
        # this is my way of randomizing ,
        #  make one that matches your liking by studying the random() built in Class
        #  or make your own !
        sounds = ['Ding Dong','Bird Chirp','Buzzz','Whistle']
        if random.randint(1,200) == 2:
            self.label_string = "Sound: "+sounds[random.randint(0,3)]
    
    def on_session_begin(self,dt):
        # place all the activities you want to run when on_session() method is called here
        self.play_tech()

        # to stop the event when the on_session() method has done its job,
        # return False  

class StackOverFLow(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root_layout = RootFloatLayout()
        return self.root_layout
    
    def in_session(self):
        # creates a Clock based event that runs the on_session_begin () once (1) every 60 seconds
        self.root_layout.label_string = "Session is on!"
        self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.root.on_session_begin, 1./60.)
        

    def stop_function(self):
        # stops calling the on_session_begin() method, even midway
        self.root_layout.label_string = "Stopped!"
        self.event.cancel()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    StackOverFLow().run()
```